# Unable to import images, getting error Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null

Tags: java, swing, netbeans

I'm trying to make a login user interface with swing.
I need images to make my UI prettier, and when trying to import them by using this code

```
MyTextField txtUser = new MyTextField();
txtUser.setPrefixIcon(newImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("/com/itenas/oop/org/uashotel/iamges/user.png")));`
```

I receive an error `Cannot invoke "java.net.URL.toExternalForm()" because "location" is null`

[image: folder structure]

these are my packages, and I clearly have the images in my package and write them with the right syntax.

Comment: My guess is that your URL should be `/iamges/user.png`.  I don't know if `iamages` is spelled correctly or if your `iamages` file is on the classpath.

Comment: Use `getClass().getResource("/com/itenas/oop/org/uashotel/images/user.png")` instead. I'd also recommend using [`ImageIO.read`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/images/loadimage.html) instead of `ImageIcon`